# data() method not working with element in jsoup

Tags: jsoup

i have an Element

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.example.com").get();
    Elements ex = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("href","tss");
```

but whenever i try getting the data from it

```
String eldata = ex.data();
```

i get an error that it cant find that method in in the ex variable from Elements class

`ex.text()` and `ex.html()` work fine but its not the data i need, so why is it saying that it cant find the method, the Elements package is imported btw, otherwise .text and .html wouldnt have worked anyway but just saying.

thanks

Comment: There is no method `data` for `Elements`. http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html . What are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: i thought this was for the Elements class http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#data-- , well when i print the ex variable, thats the data i want

Comment: When you print the ex variable, the method that gets called by default is the `toString` method. So do this `String eldata = ex.toString();`

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `data` can be found in `Element` class. `Elements` contains `Element`.
You can iterate `Elements` like this

```
for(Element e : ex) {
   System.out.println(e.data());
}
```

Since what you are trying to do is to retrieve the `String` representation of the object you can do this

```
String eldata = ex.toString();
```

In the case of `Elements` the `toString` method calls `outerHtml`.